# Multi-Tenant cube and dimension dynamic security

Tags: ssas

I need to implement a granular, hierarchical security to my dimensions and cubes (facts).

The requirement is that when the user connects to SSAS I want them to see the subset of data data which belongs to that particular tenant only.

On top of that, I need to be able to allow the user to interact with dimensions and facts she/he has the rights to. For example, if Manager A manages Person B and Manager C, who manages Person D, then when Manager A look at sales he/she needs to be able to see everybody down the hierarchy, including Manager C and Person D sales. But if that OLAP client is Manager C, then he/she only sees Person D's sales. This has to work recursively as any hierarchy (child-parent relationship) does.

My basic data set is comprised by:

- Tenant
- Customer
- Employee (self referencing entity for sales reps, managers, supervisors, etc)
- Supervisor (a many to many relationship entity that specifies additional managers to a particular employee), i.e., the Manager ID on the Employee table refers to the primary manager. If that person is managed by somebody else in addition, then this table gets populated.
- Role (employee's role including their seniority level)
- Sales
- Promotion

as for the relationships, each Tenant has multiple Customers, Employees Roles, Promotions and Sales. My transactional database is normalized to the 3rd normal form and all tenants share the same database.

I tried to denormalize the structure to the best of my knowledge when creating the dimensions and facts. For example, I have the Tenant surrogate key in the Sales fact and about any other dimension. By the way, is that something you guys would recommend?

I have researched the web and I see different approaches of implementing this design, being:

Security Wise

- factless fact table between Fact and Dimensions and user context set via USERNAME(). In my case I would have to map all Dimensions to Employees (with a primary key/foreign key approach) and add new measure groups, etc.
- use the Default member and Allowed set with STRMEMBER on each Tenant attribute, setting Visual Totals to true.

Management Hierarchy

- mostly add new dimension over a factless for each many-to-many I want to map

It looks like there is some overlap between the approaches but I am not sure how well this would perform, nor do I know if there are any other ways to implement this.

Note: our system is a product sold on the web, therefore I can't simply have one role for each Tenant, otherwise this would have been easier to solve.

Can somebody recommend an approach?

Cheers,
Robson